# Copy rows and increase Version-Column without Cursor / Loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with this structure:

```
ID    Version    Content 
-------------------------------------------------------
1     1          sometext
1     2          anothertext
1     3          someverydifferenttext
```

So all rows have the same ID but a different Version. I want to copy these rows (Insert Statement) and increase the Version-Column to the next free number.

**Expected Result:**

```
ID    Version    Content 
-------------------------------------------------------
1     1          sometext
1     2          anothertext
1     3          someverydifferenttext
1     4          sometext
1     5          anothertext
1     6          someverydifferenttext
```

Is there way to do this in a single Select-Insert Statement?

I tried with...

```
Insert Into MyTable
SELECT ID
, MAX([Version])OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [Version] DESC) + 1
,Content
FROM MyTable
```

But this does not work because MAX() would have to be evaluated again after each individual insert of a row. And the only option I currently see is a loop.

I use T-SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you could achieve this with `ROW_NUMBER` and a windowed `MAX`:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
SELECT ID,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Version) + MAX(Version) OVER () AS Version,
       Content
FROM dbo.YourTable WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5ddfd17ef57d070a66c3c27edd7ded79)

Comment: Because I was "silly", I've updated with some table hints, @OPunktSchmidt ; otherwise you could suffer race conditions.